# Ubuntu/GCC configuration issue: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, cmake

Ubuntu 14.04 here. I am trying to install and build [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) (C++ library) from source and am running into some Ubuntu/GCC config errors. It's definitely not a problem with the source code, so I don't think StackOverflow is the appropriate site for this question.

The commands I ran were:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen#3.2
mkdir eigen_build && cd eigen_build
cmake . ../eigen
```

When I run that `cmake` command I get the following errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically
```

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
        get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)

```
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically - Failed
-- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_as_m
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
    get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)

CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_as_m - Failed
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:75 (message):
    Can't link to the standard math library.  Please report to the Eigen
    developers, telling them about your platform.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/vagrant/eigen_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/vagrant/eigen_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The contents of that `CMakeError.log` file are:

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
No such file or directory

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
No such file or directory

Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically failed with the following output:

Source file was:
#include<cmath>
int main() { std::sin(0.0); std::log(0.0f); }
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test standard_math_library_linked_to_as_m failed with the following output:

Source file was:
#include<cmath>
int main() { std::sin(0.0); std::log(0.0f); }
```

Can anyone help me decipher whether this is a GCC config issue, or something wrong with Eigen's make (I **highly** doubt it)?

GCC is installed (running `gcc -v` yields `gcc version 4.8.4`). I also know `cmake` is installed (by running `cmake --help`). Just not sure if it's configured correctly. **Any ideas?**

Comment: You have `gcc` - but do you have `g++`? Try `sudo apt-get install g++` (or install it via your favorite package manager)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver (+1) - I tried that and then re-ran the `cmake` command, but am still getting the same errors.

Comment: So what does `g++ --version` say? or if that fails, `type g++`?

Comment: When I run `g++ --version` I get `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4` followed by a copyright notice.

Comment: Hmm... in that case I don't know why cmake wouldn't find it - as a workaround you could try defining it explicitly on the command line e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ . ../eigen`